# ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID with https request

Tags: java, ssl, https, websphere, websphere-liberty

I'm a novice to SSL certifications. I created a web service with Java on a cloud WebSphere Liberty server. I also created certificates by adding the following tags to server.xml

```
<featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" location="squery.keystore" type="JCEKS" password="forget1t"/>
```

However, when my application which is hosted on a different server makes a request to the websphere server, it gets an error Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
I also tried to open the websphere server by Google Chrome, and it responded with NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. What was I missing with the configuration? I really could not find any documents about that. Thanks

Comment: Here is the easiest tutorial on how to generate free valid SSL cert files for use with https     https://letsecure.me/secure-web-deployment-with-lets-encrypt-and-nginx/      The resulting SSL cert files will give you the sought after green padlock URL which is a very good starting point